# Zend framework, An error occurred Application error & * @method $this setCharset($charset) --can not re-declare setCharest

Tags: php, zend-framework

When I imported Zend library into my ZendStudio, it shows an error in the file of HeadMeta.php ---> * @method $this setCharset($charset)

The error is **"Cannot re-declare method 'setCharset' in type 'Zend_View_Helper_HeadMeta'   HeadMeta.php    /hspzf/library/Zend/View/Helper line 43 PHP Semantic Problem"**

I want to try to connect with MySQL database, but it shows **An error occurred  Application error** in the index.phtml

Can someone tell me how to solve this issues?

Comment: Make sure in your `application.ini` you have `phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1`. This will shows you error with details rather than **An error occurred Application error**.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug introduced at this [commit](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/commit/bb9458c7041a829936f9165da4f1cb6809809b01).

```
library/Zend/View/Helper/HeadMeta.php
```

`@method` is to hint magic method. I don't know how the ZF team missed this. I guess you can just delete this line.

```
 * @method $this setCharset($charset)
```